# How to calculate the voltage induced in a toroid by a charged particle moving through the center?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, voltage

I'm trying to derive the expression for the voltage induced in a toroid by a charged particle moving perpendicularly through the opening/center of the toroid? For the purposes of clarification, the center of the toroid is where the magnetic field would be zero and the electric field lines would be parallel and unbending.

I've gotten to the expression that the induced voltage is

$\varepsilon = -N \frac{\Delta \phi_B}{\Delta t}$

$\phi_B = \vec{B} \cdot \vec{A}$

$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu _0 q_e \vec{v}}{4\pi r^2}$

$d\phi = |\vec{B}||\vec{A}|cos(\theta)d\theta$

$\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{r_{tor}}{z})$

$d\theta = -\frac{r_{tor}}{r_{tor}^2 + z^2} dz$

These expressions are used in the first equation to give

$\varepsilon = -N |\vec{B}||\vec{A}|cos(tan^{-1}(\frac{r_{tor}}{z})) \frac{\Delta z}{\Delta t}$

$\varepsilon = -N |\vec{B}||\vec{A}|cos(tan^{-1}(\frac{r_{tor}}{z})) |\vec{v}|$

This doesn't seem completely correct since the distance between the moving particle and the toroid center, $z$, is changing in time. I imagine it would be more accurate to have an integral of this expression where the total voltage is the integral of the EMF as a function of time, but I'm just not convinced by my math. I also read that [here](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=28904&t=charged-particle-through-torus) that the charged particle would lose energy as it streams through the toroid. I don't know where to start with this problem. It's been many years since my advanced E&M class in college.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the assumption that the electron beam is actually a line source is the key to solving my problem. The magnetic potential is defined as

$\vec{M} = \frac{\mu_0 \mu_r}{4\pi} \int _{\Omega} \frac{J(\vec{r}',t)}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} d^3\vec{r}'$

then the magnetic field can be determined using Maxwell's equations

$\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{M}  $

$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0 \mu _r Q_e |\vec{v}_e|}{2\pi\vec{r}}$

Finally for Faraday's Law the induced voltage in the toroid is

$\varepsilon = -N \frac{\Delta \phi_B}{\Delta t}$

$\phi_b = \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \mu_0 \mu_r \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{A}$

$\Delta t = \frac{w}{|\vec{v}_e|}$

where $w$ is the width of the toroid.